# Open jQuery dialogue as login box on clicking menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I have menubar which contains links.Some links are such that they needs to be password protected.For the same reason in need to give login form for those type of links..I want to use jQuery Dialogue box as login box such that once the link has been clicked it should open login form ..

Here is my html for menu bar..

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><span>Settings</span></a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Createuser.aspx"><span>Create New Account</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want as soon as user clicks on **Create New Account** menu bar, jQuery login dialogue box should popup and once entered credentials are verified and correct it should navigate to Createuser.aspx page.

Here is my dialogue box code in html.

```
<a href="/login" class="loginlink">Log In</a>
    <div id="loginform">
        <form action="/login" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

and this is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
        $('#loginform').dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('#loginform').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false
    });
});
```

My dialogue box is opening on clicking of Login link whereas i need to use it with menu bar.

Please help me.

Comment: Where is `a.loginlink`? `e.preventDefault();` should be the next line after the `click` listener.

Comment: why can't you change selector to menu bar..not link? There is no `loginlink` shown in your html and it is unclear what parent of `menubar` is

Comment: @charlietfl sir i updated my code..how to change selector to menu bar..i am ver new in jquery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is using `css` selectors for targeting nodes.

```
$('a.loginlink').click(function(e) {
....
```

Currently, your popupbox is only applied to `a.loginlink`, which is selecting an element like `<a class="loginlink" href="...">`. If you want this to work on your menubar, then you can add the classname to your link there.

```
<li><a href="Createuser.aspx" class="loginlink"><span>Create New Account</span></a></li>
                              =================
```